# How to do looping in lisp?

Tags: clisp

Just started learning and coding lisp,
I'm trying to create a program that will continuously accept a number and stops only if and only if the last input number is twice the previous number.

Here's my code

```
 


----------


(let((a 0)
     (b 0)
     (count 0))
(loop
   (= a b))
   (princ"Enter Number: ")
   (defvar a(read))
   (format t "~% a = ~d" a)
   (setq count (1+ count))
(while
   (!= b(* a 2) || <= count 1)
   (princ "Program Terminated Normally")
)
```

Thank you

Comment: Read the [Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/) and the documentation of [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/). SBCL is written mostly in Common Lisp and is [open source](https://opensource.org/), so study its source code and take inspiration from it.

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer which definitely is not how you would do this in real life, but if you understand what it does you will understand one of the two big important things about Lisps.

(If you understand why the equivalent program would *not* work reliably in Scheme you'll also understand one of the important things about writing safe programs!  Fortunately this is Common Lisp, not Scheme, so it's OK here.)

First of all let's write a little helper function to read integers.  This is just fiddly detail: it's not important.

```
(defun read-integer (&key (prompt "Integer: ")
                          (stream *query-io*))
  ;; Read an integer.  This is just fiddly details
  (format stream "~&~A" prompt)
  (values (parse-integer (read-line stream))))
```

OK, now here's a slightly odd function called `mu` (which stands for 'mutant U'):

```
(defun mu (f &rest args)
  (apply f f args))
```

And now here is our program:

```
(defun read-integers-until-double-last ()
  (mu (lambda (c getter current next factor)
        (if (= next (* current factor))
            (values current next)
          (mu c getter next (funcall getter) factor)))
      #'read-integer
      (read-integer)
      (read-integer)
      2))
```

And here it is working:

```
> (read-integers-until-double-last)
Integer: 0
Integer: 4
Integer: 3
Integer: -2
Integer: -4
-2
-4
```

For extra mysteriosity you can essentially expand out the calls to `mu` here, which makes it either more clear or less clear: I'm not quite sure which:

```
(defun read-integers-until-double-last ()
  ((lambda (c)
     (funcall c c 
              #'read-integer
              (read-integer)
              (read-integer)
              2))
   (lambda (c getter current next factor)
     (if (= next (* current factor))
         (values current next)
       (funcall c c getter next (funcall getter) factor)))))
```

Again, this is not how you do it in real life, but if you understand what this does and how it does it you will understand quite an important thing about Lisps and their theoretical underpinnings.  This is not all (not even most) of the interesting things about them, but it is a thing worth understanding, I think.

Comment: I tried your given code in Repl.it, it works but the program did not terminated when integers double last. I don't know why

Comment: @Sharmaine: I don't know what repl.it does (it may not be reliable).  However my answer was really intended as an 'if you understand this then you've achieved enlightenment in the church of nerdy' thing rather than anything really practical: Rainer Joswig's answer is much better!

Answer (score 3):

a bit feedback

```
(let ((a 0)
      (b 0)
      (count 0))
 (loop
   (= a b))      ; here the LOOP is already over.
                 ;  You have a closing parenthesis
                 ;   -> you need better formatting
   (princ"Enter Number: ")
   (defvar a(read))
   (format t "~% a = ~d" a)
   (setq count (1+ count))
(while
   (!= b(* a 2) || <= count 1)
   (princ "Program Terminated Normally")
)
```

some improved formatting:

```
(let ((a 0)
      (b 0)
      (count 0))
  (loop
   (= a b))                  ; LOOP ends here, that's not a good idea
  (princ "Enter Number: ")
  (defvar a(read))           ; DEFVAR is the wrong construct,
                             ;   you want to SETQ an already defined variable
  (format t "~% a = ~d" a)
  (setq count (1+ count))
  (while                     ; WHILE does not exist as an operator
   (!= b(* a 2) || <= count 1)    ; This expression is not valid Lisp
   (princ "Program Terminated Normally")
   )
```

You may need to learn a bit more Lisp operators, before you really can write such loops. You also may want to use Lisp interactively and try out things, instead of trying to write code into an editor and never get feedback from a Lisp...